# Android indoor augmented reality

Tags: android, gps, augmented-reality

I am pretty new to Augmented Reality so I don't understand something. i.e. I want to create an app that I will give to users at my store [hypothetical]. Whenever they are in my store the app should show info for different sections of the store [i.e. 'this is the tools section' or 'this is the gardening section'].

What is necessary to recognize indoor locations on Android and is in this case an Augmented Reality implementation the only possible solution ? Not sure if GPS coordinates are registered indoor precisely nor whether they'll be registered on that small 'distance' at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that Bluetooth beacons is the best way to go. You can also use the strength of WiFi signals but that is vary coarse.

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard of [LLA](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tracking-configuration/optical-tracking-technologies/lla-markers/) markers? (Latitude,Longitude, Altitude Markers). They're more accurate than GPS for indoor tracking, but there are limitations (i.e show locations statically... it won't tell you you're 36 , 35 ,34 meters away as you walk towards something).